# Dependencies between messages in threads in Distruptor

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, circular-buffer, disruptor-pattern

We have a scenario in **Disruptor** where there are multiple consumers (say 2) and multiple producers (say 3) and there a *RingBuffer* between the two. [image: Producers-RingBuffers-Consumers]

The consumers read and write to a database and are slightly slow. Some messages are dependent on each other (for example #10 is dependent on #4) and could be produced by different producers. #10 should not be processed by Consumer 1 or Consumer 2 until #4 has finished. Using a RingBuffer, how can this be handled? We obviously want to avoid locks.

1. Should the producer (P1) wait for the related message to be picked up before putting this message to the RingBuffer? Can this be achieved without using locks?
2. Should the message be "batched"? Is there way to do this?
3. Is there a better approach using Disruptor?

Is this use-case suitable for Distruptor pattern? Can someone help me with an example?